# Give me some idea for Model part in my asp.net project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I make a CarManagement program, that is a list of people and everyone of them own some car. So, I have written 2 class Person and Car like in below pictures. I don't know is it exactly? Please give me some advice

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Range(1,120)]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int Asset { get; set; }
    public int CarNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

}
public class Car
{
    //public int CarID;
    // Phai la thuoc tinh
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime RegistryDay { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Is there an error/bug? What isn't working, and what are you trying to achieve?! It's very unclear just presenting code and saying "I don't know is it exactly?"

Comment: Sorry because of my unclear question. I mean that Is it my database design right? and what i should fix for my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple terms model class use to represent a table in a database. Each instance of a model class will correspond to a row within a database table.

According to your example Car class to represents Cars table in a database. Each object of a Cars class will correspond to a row within a database table, and each property of the Cars class will map to a column in the table.